# If $X_1,X_2\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y$ is one of them who is closest to an end point, find distribution of $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent, $U (0, 1)$-distributed random variables, and
let $Y$ denote the point that is closest to an endpoint. Determine the distribution of $Y$.

It's a question in chapter of "order statistic",I'm thinking about solving it without using order statistics, cuz I have no idea how to solve it in order statistics way at all. For the normal way, $$P(Y<y)=1-P(Y>y)=1-P(y<X_1<1-y,y<X_2<1-y)=1-P(y<X_1<1-y)P(y<X_2<1-y)=1-(1-2y)^2$$ so $f(y)=4-8y$, when $y<1/2$, and the way when $y>1/2$ is similar.

But the correct answer is $f(y) = 2 − 4y$ for $0 < y < 1$ , $4y − 2$ for $1 < y < 1$. 
Dose anybody can tell me how to solve this question by both order statistics way and the normal way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We derive the density function directly, in a way analogous to the way one finds the distribution of order statistics. The only interesting value of $y$ are between $0$ and $1$. We find $f_Y(y)$ for $0\lt y\lt \frac{1}{2}$.

The probability that $y$ is between $y$ and $y+dy$, for "small" $dy$, is approximately $f_Y(y)\,dy$. Or, if one feels like being more precise, the probability that $Y$ lies between $y$ and $y+h$ is $f_Y(y)h +o(h)$.

In order for $Y$ to lie in this interval, we want either (i) $X_1$ lies in this interval, and $X_2$ lies roughly in the interval $(y,1-y)$, or (ii) $X_2$ lies in this interval, and $X_1$ lies roughly in the interval $(y,1-y)$. The events (i) and (ii) are equiprobable, and disjoint. We find the probability of (i).

The probability that $X_1$ lies in the interval from $y$ to $y+dy$ is $dy$. Given this, the probability that $X_2$ lies in the interval $(y,1-y)$ is $1-2y$. Thus the probability of (i) is $\approx (1-2y)\,dy$. Taking (ii) into account, we find that the probability $Y$ lies in the interval is $\approx (2-4y)\,dy$. This is mildly inexact, there is a "second order infinitesimal" involved.

It follows that
$$f_Y(y)\,dy\approx (2-4y)\,dy,$$
and the result follows.

**Remark:** The assertion that (for $y\lt \frac{1}{2}$) we have $\Pr(Y\gt y)$ is $\Pr(y\lt X_1\lt 1-y)\Pr(y\lt X_2\lt 1-y)$ was not correct. Roughly speaking, this is because we can have $Y\le y$ in many ways. Let $t\le y$. If $t$ is equal to $y$, or close, and $X_1=t$, we do indeed want $y\lt X_2\lt 1-y$. But if $t$ is smaller, say $y/2$, and $X_1=y/2$, our condition on $X_2$ changes, it can be allowed to roam up to $1-y/2$.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer really helps me a lot, it's a super good way of considering!

Comment: You are welcome. I thought I might use this kind of language because it is often used to derive the distribution of order statistics other than Max or Min, for which there is simple direct access to the cdf.